# Rewrite rule, preserving query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs like this:

URL requested:

```
/admin/cars/
/admin/cars/edit/?id=10
```

Becomes:

```
/admin/blog/?type=cars 
/admin/blog/edit/?type=cars&id=10
```

I can accomplish the first with:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/cars(/?)$ /admin/blog/?type=cars
```

How can I do the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).